# python Infinite Loop append in multiprocessing.manger list

Tags: python, performance, python-multiprocessing

**Why this code isnt working:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import pcap, string, sys


def f(a, p):
    try:
        while True:
            a.append(p.next())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'stop'


def g(a):
    # print a
    while True:
        print a[len(a)-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # num = Value('d', 0.0)
    manager = Manager()
    l = manager.list([])
    p = pcap.pcapObject()
    dev = sys.argv[1]
    p.open_live(dev, 65000, 0, 100)
    p.setfilter(string.join(sys.argv[2:], ' '), 0, 0)

    p = Process(target=f, args=(l, p))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    a = Process(target=g, args=(l,))
    a.start()
    a.join()

    # print l
    # print len(l)
```

**while below code is working fine:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import pcap, string, sys


def f(a, p):
    try:
        while len(a) < 100:
            a.append(p.next())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'stop'


def g(a):
    # print a
    while True:
        print a[len(a)-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # num = Value('d', 0.0)
    manager = Manager()
    l = manager.list([])
    p = pcap.pcapObject()
    dev = sys.argv[1]
    p.open_live(dev, 65000, 0, 100)
    p.setfilter(string.join(sys.argv[2:], ' '), 0, 0)

    p = Process(target=f, args=(l, p))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    a = Process(target=g, args=(l,))
    a.start()
    a.join()

    # print l
    # print len(l)
```

Other Question:

- Is this is a best and fastest/optimized way way to create shared
  memory between different processes?
- Is multiprocessing.manager class for finite size  data structure. if
  no what am i doing wrong?

any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanx in advance.